# Use C to find an MPG file bitrate

Tags: c, mpeg

Is it possible to find mpg file bitrate after opening the file in c?

EDIT: It has to do with video. not mp3. It is not clear whether it is 1,2 or 4 as of yet. Is the header standard different for each? I did find the mp3 article on wiki but I haven't found mpeg 1,2,4 header structure information

Comment: Please be more precise. MPEG is a container format, MPEG-1, MPEG-2 and MPEG-4 are video formats.

Comment: 1 and 2 are basically the same thing, but 4 is completely different...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is part of the header, you didn't specify which type of mpg, so I'll go with MP3, but it's the same idea for all.

In wikipedia, you can see the [file header structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure), in this structure you can see the location of the bit rate (bytes 17-20). just read them.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it, but for that you need to know the specific header formats of the file type that you are trying to get data from.

If you don't have any limitations on the libraries to use, I would suggest you to use libavformat and [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) that are provided by the [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) project.

Here are some tutorials if you want to try these libraries:

http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html

[How to Write a Video Player in Less Than 1000 Lines](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/)

Comment: Some of your links are not working anymore.